# jupyter notebook kernel dies when running dask compute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I have a large csv file (~25GB) with a length of 8529090 and when I try to run the following the kernel dies. Running on a MacBook Pro with 16GB RAM.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_csv('data/cleaned_news_data.csv')
ddf = ddf[(ddf.type != 'none')].compute()
```

Any ideas to work around it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's your RAM capacity?

Comment: I have a 16GB RAM and if I close everything not needed I have about 5-8GB available.

Comment: Tried the same thing on a gradient machine at paperspace with 30GB RAM and had the same issue.

Comment: I think for 25 GB data you need more than 30 GB. because out of 30 gb 1 gb will be unusable, 4 gb may used by other apps. to read 25 gb data you need some more space to perform read operation. So it's recommend to increase your ram size. or else if you don't want to process all files at a time read it as chunk perform required operations, then save it as processed chunk file. in this method you can make sure you have a space for other required operations.

Comment: Thanks @MohamedThasinah, but isn't that the point of using dask because it is partitioning the data. Or do I misunderstand something here? I will give your recommended process of using chunks a try.

Comment: From the dask doc: `This turns a lazy Dask collection into its in-memory equivalent. For example a Dask.array turns into a numpy.array() and a Dask.dataframe turns into a Pandas dataframe. The entire dataset must fit into memory before calling this operation.`

Comment: Thank you, @MohamedThasinah. Should have read the doc first.

Comment: I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: That is in regard to dask compute function `https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you comment above, calling compute turns the result into an in-memory object, so if your result doesn't fit in memory then you're out of luck.

Typically people compute smaller results (for example the inputs to a plot) or they write very large results to disk.